# Implicit differentiation - Second derivative using Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative, differentiation

The equation is `4*x^2-2*y^2==9`. Using implicit differentiation, I can find that the second derivative of `y` with respect to `x` is `-9/y^3`, which requires a substitution in the final step.

I am trying to duplicate this answer using Matlab's symbolic toolbox. I did find some support for the first derivative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531928/is-there-a-way-to-do-implicit-differentiation-in-matlab), and was successful finding the first derivative.

```
clear all
syms x y f
f=4*x^2-2*y^2-9
sol1=-diff(f,x)/diff(f,y)
```

But I am unable to continue onward to find the second derivative with the final simplification (replacing `4*x^2-2*y^2` with `9`).

Can someone show me how to do this in Matlab?

Comment: Post your actual code instead of linking to another question.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html#btwp91l-1) help?

Comment: Are you looking for this? `sol = -diff(f,x,2)/diff(f,y,2)`

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo The code sol = -diff(f,x,2)/diff(f,y,2) returns an answer of sol=2, which is an incorrect answer. The final answer should be -9/y^3.

Comment: @beaker Sorry, there are no examples of implicit differentiation on that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no direct way to obtain an implicit second derivative in Matlab. And working with implicit functions in Matlab can be fairly tricky. As a start, your variable `y` is implicitly a function of `x` s you should define it as such:

```
clear all
syms y(x) % defines both x and y
f = 4*x^2-2*y^2-9
```

Here `y(x)` is now what is called an [arbitrary or abstract symbolic function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-functions.html), i.e., one with no explicit formula. Then take the derivative of `f` with respect to `x`:

```
s1 = diff(f,x)
```

This returns a function in terms of the implicit derivative of `y(x)` with respect to `x`, `diff(y(x), x)` (in this case `diff(y)` is shorthand). You can solve this function for `diff(y)` algebraically with [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) and [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html):

```
syms dydx % arbitrary variable
s2 = subs(s1,diff(y),dydx)
s3 = solve(s2,dydx)
```

This yields the first implicit derivative. You can then take another derivative of this expression to obtain the second implicit derivative as a function of the first:

```
s4 = diff(s3,x)
```

Finally, substitute the expression for the first implicit derivative into this and simplify to obtain the final form:

```
s5 = simplify(subs(s4,diff(y),s3))
```

This yields `(2*(y(x)^2 - 2*x^2))/y(x)^3`. And then you can eliminate `x` using the original expression for `f` with further substitution and solving:

```
syms x2
f2 = subs(f,x^2,x2)
x2 = solve(f2,x2)
s6 = subs(s5,x^2,x2)
```

Finally, you can turn this back into an explicit algebraic expression with a final substitution, if desired:

```
s7 = subs(s6,y,'y')
```

This yields your solution of `-9/y^3`.

This whole process can be written more concisely (but very unclearly) as:

```
clear all
syms y(x) dydx x2
f = 4*x^2-2*y^2-9;
s1 = solve(subs(diff(f,x),diff(y),dydx),dydx)
s2 = simplify(subs(subs(subs(diff(s1,x),diff(y),s1),x^2,solve(subs(f,x^2,x2),x2)),y,'y'))
```

There are many other ways to achieve the same result. See also these two tutorials: [[1]](http://www.math.ku.edu/~csu/Fall%202012/Implicit%20differentiation%20for%20second%20order%20derivative.pdf), [[2]](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-b-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/session-13-implicit-differentiation/MIT18_01SCF10_ex13sol.pdf).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant presentation. I'm using matlab 2014b, so I had to do s5=simplify(subs(s4,diff(y(x),x),s3)) because D(y)(x) did not show up; rather 2/y(x) - (2*x*diff(y(x), x))/y(x)^2 showed up for s4. One final question would be, how can I expand the numerator and replace 4x^2-2y^2 with -9?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer to address that. Lot's of ugly substitutions to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

It's been almost four years since I asked this question, and got brilliant help from horchler, but I've discovered another method using the chain rule.

```
syms x y
f=4*x^2-2*y^2-9
dydx=-diff(f,x)/diff(f,y)
d2ydx2=diff(dydx,x)+diff(dydx,y)*dydx

d2ydx2=simplifyFraction(d2ydx2,'Expand',true)

s1=solve(f,x)
subs(d2ydx2,x,s1(2))
```

Comment: @horchler Just added another method. Again, thanks for your help.